# Trouble with UrlManager in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I have a `directions` module  in my Yii2 app in which in `DefaultController` i have two actions `index` and `view`.

I need to create link with slug `site.ru/directions/allergology`to use it with

```
 public function actionView($url) {
 }
```

I created URL:

```
<li><a href="<?=Url::to(['/directions/view','url' => $items->url]); ?>"><?=$items->name?></a></li>
```

And I added rules in `UrlManager`:

```
 '<module:directions>/<url:\w+>' => '<module>/view'
```

but i getting `Page Not Found (#404)` - `yii\base\InvalidRouteException: Unable to resolve the request "directions/view".`

I tried to use some rules like

```
'<module:directions>/<url:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>/view',
'<module:directions>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
'<module:directions>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
```

But it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot skip controller name in this case - you need to specify it as a part of route in your rules:

```
 'directions/<url:\w+>' => 'directions/default/view',
```

And use full route on creating URLs:

```
<li><a href="<?=Url::to(['/directions/default/view','url' => $items->url]); ?>"><?=$items->name?></a></li>
```